# Vagrant This site can’t be reached

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have tried to setup vagrant for my project but I cannot connect to my localhost website. I already set up in /etc/hosts/ file. Try everyone vagrant command I can like

`vagrant up
vagrant reload`

but I can't connect to my localhost . Does anybody know how to fix it

My yaml config

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: D:/Work/crm
      to: /home/vagrant/code/crm

sites:
    - map: crm.local
      to: /home/vagrant/code/crm/public

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

vagrant up last log

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add 192.168.10.10 to your hosts file.

For example if you're using Windows, you will find the hosts file in "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" this path.

At the end of the file you can add it. Something like this

```
192.168.10.10               laravel.test
```

Hope this helps.